# Microsoft's symbol files for Windows UWP debugging in VS C++ 2015 aren't working?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to debug a UWP app for Windows 10 desktop and see the contents of a object (in this case a BluetoothLEDevice object) at a breakpoint. At first, the symbol file was missing, so I went into options and turned on the fetching from the Microsoft Symbol Servers. However, now when I debug, I still am not seeing anything beyond raw object data, along with this message:

`<No type information available in symbol file for Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll>   Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice`

[image: error example]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I could repro this issue using a sample in my side, it really couldn't show the object information in the debugging local window even if the symbol file was loaded normally in X86 target.

[image]

But if I change the platform target from X86 to X64, I will get the information like the following screen shot:

[image]

It really loaded the different version dll files and pdb files after I changed the target. But not found the real reason why it has the specific requirement for the platform target, I use the windows 10 64 bit machine.

Since I could repro this issue, I submitted a report here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3120892/microsofts-symbol-files-for-windows-uwp-debugging-in-vs-c-2015-arent-working

You could also check the latest update information from above feedback.

Comment: Nice find. I was using x86, but unfortunately, changing "Platform" to "x64" in the Configuration Manager didn't fix the issue, nor did switching over to the "x64" active solution platform. Did you change anything else when you switched platforms? I added a picture of the error to the question.

Comment: @vestlen, I just use the default VS settings, and then change the platform to X64 in my side. If possible, you could reset your VS settings, change the target, debug it again. In addition, you could also add your comments in that report, the product team would share the latest information there.